# Is there an introspection/reflection/catalog mechanism to get to the schema of FQL tables?

Tags: schema, facebook-fql

I'm trying to build a FQL query builder, and trying to avoid the painful task of translating from doc pages into my own schema implementation. Besides, doing that is going to lead to a very brittle system that will break each time FB changes the schema. Appreciate any pointers ....